# C++ - sending Curl requests gives the response in the console without printing it

Tags: c++, curl

Here is my code:

```
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
curl = curl_easy_init();
std::string json_message = "{\r\n    \"email\":\"test@abv.bg\",\r\n    \"password\":\"asdasdasd\"\r\n}";

if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.examle.com/myUrl");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_DEFAULT_PROTOCOL, "https");
    struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Authorization: Bearer secretkeyHere");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
    const char *data = json_message.c_str();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);
    curl_easy_perform(curl);
}
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

The problem is that when I execute that code the response of the http request is printed directly into my console application. I would like to store the response in a string without printing it into the console **without** intention.

Do you see why it is printed unintentionally and how can I store the response in a string?

Comment: Set `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`

Comment: @HattedRooster can you please form up a complete solving answer ?

Comment: https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html this should help. The default is `fwrite` which is standard output.

Comment: @HattedRooster `fwrite()` itself is not standard output, it just writes to whatever `FILE*` it is given. The default `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` callback is `fwrite()`, yes, but the default `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` is `FILE* stdout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, curl writes the received data to `stdout`.  You can change that by using `curl_easy_setopt()` to specify a custom [`CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html) callback, giving it a `string*` pointer via [`CURLOPT_WRITEDATA`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEDATA.html).  For example:

```cpp
static size_t writeToString(void *data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
    std::string *str = static_cast<std::string*>(userp);
    str->append(static_cast<char*>(data), realsize);
    return realsize;
}

...

CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
if (curl) {
    ...
    std::string respStr;
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &writeToString);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &respStr);

    CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    // use respStr as needed...

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```